# NGINX Multiple Site Config One IP

Tags: php, nginx, dns, server, webserver

I have a virtual machine that my company uses for a web server. We an internal PHP application on it and now are needing to add a site to this server. The problem is the VM on has one IP. I have Windows DNS Manager set to point to this IP but it only will pull up the main site. Is there a way to configure nginx to where it will pick which site to pull up?

Here is my first site config:

```
 server {

  server_name develop.aspirion.com;


  root /var/www/vhosts/develop.aspirion.com;
  index index.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {

    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
 }
}
```

Here is my second site config:

```
server {

server_name aspirion.com;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/aspirion.com-access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/aspirion.com-error.log;

root /var/virtual/aspirion.com/master/current/webroot;
index index.php;

location / {
  # error_page 404 /index.php;

  location = / {
    error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html|xml)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    tcp_nodelay off;
    open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
    open_file_cache_valid 45s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
  }
  location ~* ^.+\.(?:pdf|pptx?)$ {
    expires 30d;
    tcp_nodelay off;
  }

  # TODO: never allow private files inside the web root?
  location ^~ /sites/default/files/private/ {
    internal;
  }

  location ~* ^(?:.+\.(?:htaccess|make|txt|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(?:\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|/Entries.*|/Repository|/Root|/Tag|/Template)$ {
    return 404;
  }

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}

location = /index.php {
  fastcgi_pass phpcgi;
}

location = /.git {
  return 404;
}

location = /patches {
  return 404;
}

location = /backup {
  return 404;
}

location = /robots.txt {
  access_log off;
}

location = /humans.txt {
  access_log off;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}

location = /rss.xml {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}

location = /sitemap.xml {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
  try_files /favicon.ico =204;
}

location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
  return 404;
}
}

server {
server_name munin.aspirion.com;

include sites-available/admin.conf;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal for Nginx to serve several domains from a single IP address.

Browsers resolve the DNS for both domains to the same IP, and then forward the traffic to port 80 on that IP address. Nginx is listening there and checks the incoming `Host:` header and matches it against the `server_name` values in your configuration. Your problem is not related to having two domains on one IP address. Try this things:

1. After changing the Nginx config file, make sure to reload Nginx.
2. Make sure that all domains are actually enabled. (Ie: If yo put files in `sites-available`, make sure there are symlinks to `sites-enabled`.
3. Try simpler configurations. Try a configuration with just the one domain, and then try a configuration with just the other domain. Try a configuration that just serves simple static files.
4. Check your DNS. All domains you wish to involve to should ultimately resolve to the IP of the VM. Check each one: `dig +short example.com`.
5. Try changing the order the configurations appear in the Nginx config file. This *shouldn't* apply because I don't see wildcard matching, but if nothing else is working...

Your Nginx configurations show that you have separate `server` blocks with unique `server_name` values so generally your configuration looks good for hosting multiple domains on a single IP address.

(If you happen to have stripped out SSL configuration, there could be related issue, but I'm assuming not based on your configuration).